# response()->json() returns with "resource" wrap - Laravel 5.6.*

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a problem regarding the response JSON of my API. I used a resource, since I wanted to limit what data to send back to the client. It was properly giving my intended response before, but when I opened my project again, the response changed.

Here's are parts of my code:

**api.php**

```
Route::get('admin/adminuserdetails/{adminUser}', 'AdminsController@AdminUserDetails');
```

**Sample URL:**
http://localhost:8000/api/admin/adminuserdetails/1

**Controller**

```
public function AdminUserDetails(AdminUsers $adminUser){
    return response()->json(new AdminUserAccessDetails($adminUser), 200);
}
```

**AdminUsers Model**

```
class AdminUsers extends Model
{

//
   protected $table = 'AdminUsers';
   protected $primaryKey = 'AdminUserId';
   protected $guarded = [];
}
```

**AdminUserAccessDetails Resource**

```
class AdminUserAccessDetails extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        //return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
        'adminUserId' => $this->AdminUserId,
        'adminFirstName' => $this->AdminFirstName,
        'adminLastName' => $this->AdminLastName,
        'modulesAllowed' => $this->ModulesAllowed,
        'actionsAllowed' => $this->ActionsAllowed
        ];
    }
}
```

**Sample response (before, my intended response)**

```
{
    "adminUserId": 1,
    "adminFirstName": "asdfasdf",
    "adminLastName": "asdfsadf",
    "modulesAllowed": "",
    "actionsAllowed": ""
}
```

**Sample response (now)**

```
{
        {
        "resource": {
            "adminUserId": 1,
            "adminFirstName": "asdfasdf",
            "adminLastName": "asdfsadf",
            "adminEmail": "asdfsadf@fsafsa.com",
            "adminPassword": "l6wfDtAaYAp6aM04TU++9A==",
            "authToken": "68bbc9fc7eb08c9f6d96f6b63d30f056",
            "fCMToken": null,
            "profileImage": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5d0d65256e8c2b15a8d00e8b208565f1?d=identicon&s=512",
            "userTypeId": "0",
            "status": "A",
            "createDate": "2018-06-26 16:01:43.947",
            "updateDate": "2018-06-26 16:01:44.143",
            "modulesAllowed": "",
            "actionsAllowed": ""
        },
        "with": [],
        "additional": []
    }
```

I didn't change anything, but when I tested it again (not only in this particular route), everything that uses any resource is now enclosed within that resource wrap, and I can't seem to find the reason why.

I tried implementing the same logic with another clean project, and it's working perfectly.

What's causing this and how do I get my intended response back?

**Edit 1:**
I tried to change my return, I removed the "response()->json()" code so my controller would look like:

```
public function AdminUserDetails(AdminUsers $adminUser){
        //return response()->json(new AdminUserAccessDetails($adminUser), 200);
        return new AdminUserAccessDetails($adminUser);
    }
```

The response of this edit is now a bit closer to my intended output:

```
{
    "data": {
        "adminUserId": 1,
        "adminFirstName": "asdfasdf",
        "adminLastName": "asdfsadf",
        "modulesAllowed": "",
        "actionsAllowed": ""
    }
}
```

However I still prefer using the response()->json() so that I can return a proper HTTP response code..

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is you are sending a Laravel Object as API response. Remember, Laravel Core instance object add some properties/methods to manage/use easily inside your code.

I may recommend you create a new Class or Associative array to encapsulate specifics properties and later send it.

For Example:

```
public function AdminUserDetails(AdminUsers $adminUser){

    // Example with Object
    $Object = new YourClass(); // you can define with yours wished properties
    $Object->PropertyA = $adminUser->Property1;
    $Object->PropertyB = $adminUser->Property2;
    // ...

    return response()->json($Object, 200);

    // Example with Associative Array
    $AssociateArray = array(
        "PropertyA" => $adminUser->Property1,
        "PropertyB" => $adminUser->Property2,
        // ...
    );

    return response()->json($AssociateArray, 200);

}
```

I hope be useful.

Comment: Hmmmm.. this can be a workaround solution, but one problem may be that: what if I need almost all of it except for one field for a specific return only? I may have to list all the fields again except for one, which would make the code longer and tedious to make..